# How do I compile a c program made in sublime text?

Tags: compiling, c, sublime-text

I am new to programming and I used sublime text but the gcc command dos not work and I need help to compile the code

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you're actually trying and what it's saying in response? "dos (sic) not work" isn't helpful to either of us.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you just run `gcc filename.c` and that'll generate an `a.out` executable. As a shortcut, you can also run `make filename` and it'll create a binary with the same filename (without the extension). By example:

```
$ cat helloworld.c 
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}

$ gcc helloworld.c
$ ./a.out 
Hello, world!

$ make helloworld
cc     helloworld.c   -o helloworld
$ ./helloworld 
Hello, world!
```

Comment: In sublime text, there is also the option to type CTRL+B from the application and it will compile whatever is saved, however interaction directly with the terminal is still necessary to run it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install build essentials:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
```

then you write your program on Sublime Text, and save with *.c extension, example: my_program.c

then you open a terminal, with "ctrl+alt+t" and go to the folder where you put the program.

then type on the command line:

```
gcc my_program.c -o my_program
```

and for execute program:

```
./my_program
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has compiling C built in. You can do this is in the terminal

Got to the directory where your file is:

```
cd /directory/of/your/file
```

Then:

```
gcc filename.c -o name
```

gcc is the command for compiling c
name is the name of your new executable, which you can execute like this:

```
./name
```